# Problem with the hub.load function in tensorflow ( TypeError: Autotrack object is not callable)

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow, nlp

I have a problem with loading pretrained module for an NLP task and the problem is because of the tf migration I suppose. Tensorflow website says that the problem might be sorted if the signature variable is given correctly. Can you help me correct this code ?

TypeError: 'AutoTrackable' object is not callable

[code]

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
# enabling the pretrained model for trainig our custom model using tensorflow hub
module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3"
embed = hub.load(module_url)

# creating a method for embedding and will using method for every input layer 
def UniversalEmbedding(x):
    return embed(tf.squeeze(tf.cast(x, tf.string)), signature='default', as_dict=True)["default"]
```